# Which class implements Interface Action method Perform()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, interface, webdriver

I'm new to selenium, I'm trying to understand Interface Action and Class Actions. My understanding is that Interface Action just has one method Perform().
However I see that class Actions also has the method Perform().  Because class Actions does not Implement from Interface Action so it's method Perform
is not overridden method of Interface.  My question is if class Actions does not Implement Interface Action, which class implements perform method then?
Am I wrong to say Class Actions does not implement Interface Action?  I didn't see any document saying it does.

```
org.openqa.selenium.interactions
Interface Action
```

```
All Known Implementing Classes:

ButtonReleaseAction, ClickAction, ClickAndHoldAction, CompositeAction, ContextClickAction, DoubleClickAction, 
DoubleTapAction, DownAction, FlickAction, KeyDownAction, KeyUpAction, LongPressAction, MoveAction, MoveMouseAction, 
MoveToOffsetAction, PauseAction, ScrollAction, SendKeysAction, SingleTapAction, UpAction
```

Answer (score 0):

`Actions` is an utility class. It does not implement `Action` interface indeed. It is designed using `Builder` design pattern so that you can call the chain of methods each of which would increment the state of the original object.

There are several classes which implement `Action` interface. You can use any IDE to trace which they are (`DoubleClickAction`, `KeyUpAction`, etc.).

If you will observe those `Action` implementations you will also see that they are deprecated currently. This is because there is new concept of `Interaction`. That utility `Actions` class supports both. Each time you add new "action" to the action chain using "Actions" class it adds corresponding `Action` implementation to its internal storage of actions and it also adds corresponding implementation of `Interaction` to a sequence of interactions.

Then when you do `build()` it chooses which to use in this particular case.

Answer (score -1):

In short the `org.openqa.selenium.interactions` package contains the following **Interfaces**:

- [*`Action`*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Action.html): Interface representing a single user-interaction action.
- *`Encodable`*: This interface allows a custom Interaction to be JSON encoded for the W3C wire format.
- *`HasInputDevices`*: Interface implemented by each driver that allows access to the raw input devices.
- *`HasTouchScreen`*: Interface implemented by each driver that allows access to touch screen capabilities.
- *`InputSource`*: Models an input source as defined and used by the W3C WebDriver spec.
- *`Interactive`*: Indicates that a class can be used with the W3C WebDriver Actions commands.
- *`IsInteraction`*: Interface to help us transition code to The New World
- *`Keyboard`*: Interface representing basic, low-level keyboard operations.
- *`Locatable`*
- *`Mouse`*: Interface representing basic mouse operations.
- *`TouchScreen`*: Interface representing basic touch screen operations.

It also contains the following **Classes**:

- [*`Actions`*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html): The user-facing API for emulating complex user gestures.
- *`ButtonReleaseAction`*: Deprecated
- *`ClickAction`*: Deprecated
- *`ClickAndHoldAction`*: Deprecated
- *`CompositeAction`*: An action for aggregating actions and triggering all of them at the same time.
- *`ContextClickAction`*: Deprecated
- *`DoubleClickAction`*: Deprecated
- *`Interaction`*: Used as the basis of Sequences for the [W3C WebDriver spec Action commands](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#actions).
- *`KeyDownAction`*: Models a [key input source](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-key-input-source).
- *`KeyInput`*: Deprecated
- *`MoveMouseAction`*: Deprecated
- *`MoveToOffsetAction`*: Deprecated
- *`Pause`*: Indicates that a given [InputSource](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/InputSource.html) should pause for a given duration.
- *`PauseAction`*: Deprecated
- *`PointerInput`*: Models a [pointer input source](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-pointer-input-source).
- *`PointerInput.Origin`*:
- *`SendKeysAction`*: Deprecated
- *`Sequence`*: A sequence of action objects for a given InputSource for use with the [W3C Action commands](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#actions).

---

### [perform()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#perform--)

`perform()` is a method from [*Class Actions*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) defined as:

```
public void perform()
```

is a convenience method for performing the actions without calling `build()` first.